# How do I derive a typeclass for a user defined type?

Tags: purescript

How do I derive the equality typeclass for the following custom defined type?

```
type Address =
  { street :: String
  , city   :: String
  , state  :: String
  }

type Entry =
  { firstName :: String
  , lastName  :: String
  , address   :: Address
  }


derive instance eqEntry :: Eq Entry
```

On compilation I receive the following error:

```
  Cannot derive a type class instance, because the type declaration for Entry could not be found.
```

This confuses me as from what I can see the type declaration for Entry is just above the statement which derives the typeclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type synonyms cannot have class instances. In order to have instances, you'd have to declare `Entry` as `data` or `newtype`:

```
newtype Entry = Entry 
    { firstName :: String 
    , lastName :: String 
    , address :: Address 
    } 

derive instance eqEntry :: Eq Entry
```